# HDMI needs reset after boot -- Surface Pro Dock w Projector

Tags: video, hdmi, microsoft-surface

I have a Surface 7 Pro with the Microsoft Dock. Plugged into the two video ports are a projector and a monitor.

The monitor *always* works, never any issues.

The Epson projector almost always needs me to unplug and replug the hdmi cable. Either it fails to see signal at all, or it gets video but no audio.

I have tried replacing some of the cables, and have yet to make any difference in the behavior. The current cable setup to the projector is:

- USB-C -> HDMI 6' cable by UNI
- Female to Female adapter  (I have tried replacing this)
- 25' "GearIT" HDMI cable

If I could reset the hdmi port from the OS... that would be an improvement... but preferably it would all "just work."

What might the path be?

Comment: Is the projector's HDMI cable active or passive, and what version of HDMI & HDCP is the Surface and projector? This sounds exactly like a home theater HDMI signal authentication/encryption handshake issue on the projector side _(for home  theater, you'd power off and unplug all components, then plug-in and power on in the following sequence: TV/Monitor, Receiver, Video source)_. HDMI cable quality does matter, especially the firmware chips in the cable - what brand/model of cable are you using? _(General FYI: [MonoPrice](https://www.monoprice.com/) makes phenomenal lifetime warrantied cables)_

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ As to resetting the HDMI port on the surface, it's likely not possible since HDMI communication is at the driver, and possibly kernel, level(s) - even if it was possible, it's unlikely this would resolve the [likely] handshake issue, as resetting the handshake process requires the TV/monitor come up first, then then the video source. Also, what is the length or the projector's HDMI cable?

Comment: @JW0914 OP enhanced to include the cable information.

Comment: With additional info, likely issue is your cable setup: GearIt's HDMI is likely an active cable _(source/display on either end)_, and without proprietary upgraded firmware chips _(such as RedMere)_, 25ft is the max for the signal w/o quality issues _(from what you're experiencing to a loss of resolution/refresh rate, compounded by the female adapter and USB-C to HDMI cable)_. Likely fix is removing the female adapter and using a USB-C to HDMI female [adapter](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=21880) with the GearIt cable, else a different cable entirely, such as an HDMI over fiber optic

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ If GearIt's is passive, you may end up needing to [replace](https://www.monoprice.com/category/cables/hdmi-cables/hdmi-cables?menuDisStr=hdmi%20cables&v_master_Length_uFilter=30ft&v_master_Length_uFilter=25ft&v_master_Length_uFilter=50ft&v_master_Length_uFilter=40ft&v_master_Length_uFilter=60ft&v_HDR_uFilter=Yes&TotalProducts=7) it as well, as HDMI signals have a finite length span before amplification is required, which can be bypassed entirely via HDMI over fiber optic _(GearIt has one, MonoPrice makes [several](https://www.monoprice.com/search/index?keyword=hdmi+fiber+optic))_

Comment: If cost isn't an issue, get rid of the adapter entirely and go with a [USB-C to HDMI over fiber optic](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=38583)