# USB Composite Hub not detected, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, webcam

I've been having an issue lately with a webcam that I have above a TV quite far away from a Windows computer, not easily accessible. To reach it, I'm using a USB extension with a repeater + a second cable to get through the 15 meters distance.

*EDIT:*
[PC] < USB-A --10m-- USB-A + Repeater >< USB-A --5m-- USB-C > Webcam

Weirdly when I boot or reboot my computer, it's not detected. I have to unplug the cable and plug it back in for it to work (which is not something easily doable as it's hidden in a desk.)

I'm trying to find a way to have the computer believe the USB cable is unplugged and plugged back in, without a restart.

I thought that maybe I could have a script that disables all USB ports. I found something about changing a Registry Key to disable the ports and enable them again, but a reboot is needed after each change. So probably not a solution there.

Then I looked into DevCon to disable and re-enable the USB ports, but I only found a way to refresh the state of a USB devices which are already detected.
When everything is working properly, DevCon lists a few "USB\VID_XXXX" with 'devcon find usb*'. But after a reboot, it misses the one where the webcam is, so I can't use that.

```
USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B\...    : USB Composite Device 
USB\ROOT_HUB30\...           : USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)
USB\VID_095D&DIP_921C\...    : USB Composite Device
```

*The third item in the list is the one causing the issue*

Maybe I could use a USB extension with the repeater function as well as a switch, to turn it off and on? But I'm not sure if that's going to work at all.

Any idea on a way to solve that issue I have?

Thanks a lot for the help and have a nice day.
BigBrosy

Comment: This is likely due signal degradation/noise due to the length, repeater, and/or in conjunction w/ the USB3 hub - are you using a 15m cable and a separate repeater or is the repeater apart of the 15m [active] cable? Signal quality matters with USB3 ports and if the issue isn't the cable/repeater, it could be USB3 hub; if so, there's likely not going to be a way to resolve that as it's common for USB3 ports to create issues with USB2 devices, and using an active cable that long on a USB3 port can create a signal quality issue _(both are why motherboards are still manufactured w/ USB2 ports)_.

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ I misread the second sentence in the question - **an active USB cable shouldn't be used with a second extension**, as it's intended to be used between the device and component only _(doing so will result in signal degradation, which is likely what's occurring and this is also a common problem when doing so with [HDMI](https://superuser.com/q/1716469/529800))_. Use a [longer](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=6149) active USB cable and get rid of the second extension _(I always recommend MonoPrice since they manufacture all their cables and lifetime warranty them)_.

Comment: Hi @JW0914, I probably didn't explain myself properly. I edited the initial message with a "drawing" of the situation.

Comment: The explanation in my second comment still applies - it's signal degradation. You need a single active USB cable from point A [PC] to B [webcam]. For the webcam end, a USB C adapter can be used _(you can try a 6" USB A to C cable, but you'll want to test before permanently using it to ensure signal degradation doesn't occur)_